# How do you export data from Powershell to a Csv file into a row with existing data in other columns?

Tags: powershell

What I'm trying to do is add data to a Csv file one cell at a time based on which column it needs to be in. My current script uses the `Add-Content` cmdlet followed by `-Value ",,$data"` which inserts to the desired column based on the number of commas. However, the `Add-Content` cmdlet inserts to a new row with each call, so my data looks very fragmented.

The only other solution I've been able to find is creating a temporary object to export to the Csv (i.e. `New-Object PSObject -Property @{col1 = $data}`) but this doesn't let me insert more than one row after the header row.

My current code:

```
ForEach ($user in $subSite.Users) {
    if (($user -ne $null) -and ($user.Name -ne $null)) {
        if ($user.Roles.Name -contains "Full Control") {
            Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value ",$user"
        }
        elseif ($user.Roles.Name -contains "Site Owner") {
            Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value ",,$user"
        }
        elseif ($user.Roles.Name -contains "Site Administrator") {
            Add-Content -Path $outFile -Value ",,,$user"
        }
    }
}
```

All help appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Here's an example of what gets written to the Output file. Not that it's significant but the header is added earlier in the script.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sbye-ZU9PouOPwBOXdtke-xJooloaFRz/view?usp=sharing

Notice the fragmenting since `Add-Content` creates a new line with each call. I considered the `-NoNewLine` parameter but that wont work if I need to add a new piece of data to the same column.

Comment: Can you show some data to use for examples before and after of what you want. I am not 100% sure of the outcome. Do these CSV's only have one line of data in them? You _could_ read in the whole file and add that text on the end before you write.

Comment: I guess you are tring to pivot [Role|User] table to [Role1|Role2|Role3|...]. Do you need to append new data to the file, or you are creating a new file each time?

Comment: Have you tried simply using the `-NoNewLine` parameter for `Add-Content`?